# Change my location provider in android, when there is no proper location updates from GPS provider

Tags: android, location

I need to track users location at regular time intervals.

For this, I am calling requestLocationUpdates() in the onCreate method of my service.

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
LocationManager aLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

aLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
}
```

Normally I get location updates in regular time intervals through this GPS_PROVIDER. However, in some area, I was not able to get location updates properly. In such points, I like to switch my requestLocationUpdates call to use the NETWORK_PROVIDER.

So that, when I cant get proper location updates from GPS_PROVIDER, I can switch my requestLocationUpdates to use the NETWORK_PROVIDER.

How can I do this? Is it correct to have some sort of condition checked and change my requestLocationUpdates() in onStatusChanged().

Suggestions please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes There is the way to do it . You can check GPS provider is available or not using `locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`  if false then use Network provider

You can also override onProviderEnabled() and onProviderDisabled() to switch from GPS to network 
mean while If you like to use library then you can use this location tracking library 
https://github.com/nagendraksrivastava/Android-Location-Tracking-Library
its nice library and perfectly working

here is the code to get the list of all provider and on the basis of that get the data so in this case you should be worry about providers

```
LocationManager mLocationManager = new LocationManager()
List<String> matchingProviders = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
for(String provider : matchingProviders ){
Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
if(location != null){
double lat = location.getLatitude();
}
```

Comment: Also, on top selva suggested me to call requestLocationUpdates() with both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER at a same time? is that correct? Can we have 2 requestLocationUpdates initialization at a same time. if it so, in some point, I can be able to get location using both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Comment: You can have but that will be a bad idea which will drain out the battery so I will not suggest to go for it ..

Comment: You can use get all provider then select the data from the provider I have edited my answer .just checkout the code

Answer (score 1):

try this code it work for me...

```
void currentlocation(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            MyContants.lat = location.getLatitude();
            MyContants.lon = location.getLongitude();
            //  Log.w(MyContants.ScanResult_TAG, "Currnet Location==="+String.valueOf(lat)+"-----"+String.valueOf(lon));
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };


    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    //GPS location updates.
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

USE Permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Can we have 2 requestLocationUpdates initialization at a same time. if it so, in some point, I can be able to get location updates using both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER. In that case, I think I may receive 2 calls to onLocationChanged() method (may be wrong, correct if I am so).

Comment: onLocationChanged() method called only Location Updated(New Location Founded) so  onLocation Change Method Call only once... Where New Location Founded... i use this i didn't get two Calls...So that i put it